# Saving an xlam file in the add-ins' directory

Tags: excel, vba

I've a xl add-in (.xlam file) which uses one of it's sheets to store data gathered from a UserForm.

If Excel closes then I'd like this file to save itself in the add-ins directory.

Currently here:
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\ExcelStartUp_ExcelVersion.xlam

In the addin's before close event I've the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Looks ok but it saves a copy of the xlam into whatever the CurDir is. So it is reproducing iself around our file system!

If I'm in one of the code windows of the xlam file and open the Immediate window then the following two lines are inconsistent!:

```
 ?ThisWorkbook.Path
 ?Thisworkbook.fullname
```

Comment: Your code works for me. It simply overwrites the add-in instead of creating a copy. Am I missing a point in your question?

Comment: @SiddharthRout .... I've edited the post. Do you have any xlam files that have been added to your C-Drive? Go to the vba editor and select one of the xlam file code windows and try running those two line?

Comment: Yes I saw the edit. My Addin lies in `C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns` and the same code that you have above in `Thisworkbook` and it simply overwrites the Add-In rather than make a copy of it.

Comment: `?ThisWorkbook.Path` returns the addins address, whereas `?thisworkbook.fullname` returns the address of the active xlsx/xlsm workbook !!

Comment: Strange. For me `?thisworkbook.Path` shows `C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns` and for `?thisworkbook.fullname
C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\sid.xlam`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - you need to open one of your addin code modules adn then try running those two lines ion the immediate window - are they consistent?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10218/discussion-between-whytheq-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: thanks for help - @Siddharth - I learned a few things in terms of debugging so not all lost

Comment: You are welcome :) Do see my ending comments in the chat :)

Comment: just clocked closing comments: I'm still not convinced that at some point `Thisworkbook.Save` isn't saving into a different directory. If excel crashes do you think this could act unpredicatably?

Comment: `If excel crashes do you think this could act unpredicatably? ` Honestly, I wouldn't know that. Like I mentioned in the comments, if you change the code to what I gave, it will give you a message if it tries to create a copy from `Workbook_BeforeClose`. If it is creating a copy from some other code then it will not give you any message. My suggestion as in the Chat would be to delete all the copies and monitor if any more copies are being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this behavior - addins being saved here and there - when more than one instance of Excel is open.  (I was actually just googling it last night, but couldn't find anything confirming it.)  I've got a function called from the BeforeClose event that checks for more than one instance.

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Not ThisWorkbook.Saved Then
    If MsgBox(ThisWorkbook.Name & " Addin" & vbCrLf & "is unsaved. Save?", _
              vbExclamation + vbYesNo, "Unsaved Addin") = vbYes Then
        If ExcelInstanceCount > 1 Then
            MsgBox "More than one Excel instance running." & vbCrLf & _
               "Save cancelled", _
                vbInformation, "Sorry"
           Exit Sub
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Save
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub

Function GetExcelInstanceCount() As Long
Dim hwnd As Long
Dim i As Long
Do
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(0&, hwnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    i = i + 1
Loop Until hwnd = 0
GetExcelInstanceCount = i - 1
End Function
```

Comment: the really weird behavior I was getting Doug was if I double clicked say the code module, in the add-in, and then opened the immediate window, and then ran the two following lines `?ThisWorkbook.Path` , `?thisworkbook.fullname` they were not consistent ! ....`?thisworkbook.fullname` was not the fullname of the addin but was the fullname of the Activeworkbook!

Comment: Did you figure out what caused the first problem you wrote about - addins being saved in weird places?  Did my answer address that at all?

Comment: You say _first_ problem Doug - but I believe these are the same problem. Not tried your code yet. As I rarely have more than one instance of Excel open (on this machine) it's unlikely this'll make a difference.

Comment: I should have said "the first symptom you mentioned."  I agree that they're the same problem.  I also rarely have more than one Excel instance open, but I once had a client who did, and it was embarrassing to have my addin copied all over his computer!  Sorry this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I have been encountering the same problem and found that it is caused by the addin changing its ReadOnly status to True under certain circumstances (cannot pinpoint exactly under which circumstances but seems to be linked to having multiple instances of Excel open).

Therefore, the solution is to add a check to your code as follows:

```
If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

use the Application object's ActiveWorkbook.Save method instead of its ThisWorkbook.Save method. See this link: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/avoid-this-potential-gotcha-when-using-add-ins-to-distribute-excel-macros/

Comment: -1 The OP wants to save an AddIn. AddIns can never be activated so they will never be referenced by `ActiveWorkbook`. Therefore `ActiveWorkbook.Save` will never do what the OP wanted.